# Error while installing Jenkins slave as service "KeyUsage does not allow digital signatures"

Tags: jenkins, jnlp

I am getting following error while installing Jenkins Slave as service

I downloaded slave-agent.jnlp and running with javaws.exe

Jenkins Master is installed on ubuntu
Jenkins Slave would be on windows Machine

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: KeyUsage does not allow digital signatures
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
```

I am able to run manually like below but on every restart i have to run it manually

```
java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl https://my-jenkins:8443/computer/my-build1/slave-agent.jnlp -secret <key> -noCertificateCheck
```

How we can provide "noCertificateCheck" in jnlp file so slave launch to install it has service

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this, because I'm having the exact same issue when running jenkins in kubernetes cluster.

Comment: Not yet just using java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl